# HTML Table row header size is shrinking when using the expander and displaying the content below it

Tags: html, css, xslt

If I make the table-layout property to fixed and word-wrap to break-word the table row header size is shrinking with the following setting in the xsl.

```css
table
{
    table-layout: fixed ;       
}
table tr th{
    font-size: 68%;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:center;
    background:#2674a6;
    white-space: wrap;
    word-wrap:nowrap;
}
table tr td{
    font-size: 68%;
    background:#eeeee0;
    white-space: wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```

Here is how it looks when HTML is rendered for the first time

[image: Default size]

and on expanding the + symbol the table is shrinking in its size as shown here in

[image: on expanding]

Please suggest how to word wrap the content with the fixed layout for the table without shrinking its size on expanding.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @MarkNg The question (why does the table shrink on expanding) got lost during an edit. I've added it back in. Sorry about the confusion! The question can't be answered until the OP provides their HTML and JS, by the way.

Comment: white-space: wrap;, is this valid? also, what is the code for expanding?

Comment: @MrLister no problem, agree with the question can't be answered until code is provided.